# Django rest framework updating time using EPOCH time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to take a form that has a field "starttime" that is in EPOCH and convert it to

1. python datetime
2. fieldname = "created"

when I have:

## models.py

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

## serializers.py

```
import time
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    starttime  = serializers.SerializerMethodField('epoch')

    def epoch(self, obj):
        """ Return epoch time for a datetime object or ``None``"""
        try:
            return int(time.mktime(obj.created.timetuple()))
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return None

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('starttime')
```

If I:

"GET" /snippets/1/

> > {"id":1, 'starttime':13232111}

I want to be able to do:

"POST" /snippets/1/ {"id":1, 'starttime':1}

> > {"id":1, 'starttime':1}

right now, it just ignores the request.  I am forced to use unix epoch times to conform to existing API's.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to write your own serializer Field sub-class with overridden `to_native()` and `from_native()` for the actual conversion.  Here's my attempt:

```
class UnixEpochDateField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        """ Return epoch time for a datetime object or ``None``"""
        import time
        try:
            return int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return None

    def from_native(self, value):
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value))
```

And then use that field in your `Serializer` definition:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    starttime  = UnixEpochDateField(source='created')
```

Comment: When I did this I got:  'Snippet' object has no attribute 'starttime' 
after changing the SnippetSerializer to above.  It no longer sees "starttime" as a Field

Comment: Ensure your have the the `source` parameter in your field definition set the the same as the field on the model (your model field was named `created` in this case).  If you're still having trouble, please post a gist of your entire serializers file and I can help you identify the collision.

Comment: Cool I changed your line to:  
starttime  = UnixEpochDateField(source  = 'created')

Comment: side question:  in doing this, how do I validate the incoming {"starttime": }, to ensure that it is a greater than 0, and convertable to int?  I tried to add a "validate_starttime" to the SnippetSerializer but it seems to get called BEFORE form validation?  Is there a way to do it with form validation?

Comment: Yes, much like forms, you can either: A) add a method named `validate_<field>` to your serializer and raise `serializers.ValidationError` or B) set `validators` on the field to a list of validation functions.   Here's your spirit guide: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#validation

Comment: This is not aware of timezones, you will get back wrong unix epoch timestamps if your datetime objects are in a different timezone than GMT/Greenwich. Use this instead:
https://gist.github.com/hammadzz/fe8f35c4b4344dd6ce9f73d23e825c96

Answer (score 18):

Adapting Kevin Stone code for Django Rest Framework 3:

```
class UnixEpochDateField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        """ Return epoch time for a datetime object or ``None``"""
        import time
        try:
            return int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return None

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        import datetime
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Kevin Stone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19377877/3694224), I've created [timezone aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts) serializer fields, including a `UnixEpochDateField`. The actual conversion methods are static because I've found them useful elsewhere in my code.

```
class UnixEpochDateTimeField(DateTimeField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        """
        to_native method is responsible for turning the 
        Python object into a simple, serializable value.
        Here: return epoch time for a datetime object or `None`
        """
        return self.datetime_to_epoch(value)

    def from_native(self, value):
            return self.epoch_to_datetime(value)

    @staticmethod
    def datetime_to_epoch(value):
        try:
            return int(calendar.timegm(value.utctimetuple()))
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def epoch_to_datetime(value):
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(value)).replace(tzinfo=utc)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            raise ValidationError('%s is not a valid value' % value)


class UnixEpochDateField(DateField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        return self.date_to_epoch(value)

    def from_native(self, value):
            return self.epoch_to_date(value)

    @staticmethod
    def date_to_epoch(value):
        try:
            return int(calendar.timegm(value.timetuple()))
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def epoch_to_date(value):
        try:
            return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(value))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            raise ValidationError('%s is not a valid value' % value)
```

Comment: Imports needed:
from rest_framework import serializers
import datetime
import calendar

There were some changes to the serializer class in DRF 3.0 so do the following:
change from_native(self, value) to to_representation(self, value)
change from_native(self, value) to to_internal_value(self, value)

Still confused? See my gist https://gist.github.com/hammadzz/fe8f35c4b4344dd6ce9f73d23e825c96

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you need to deserialize the `starttime` field and use it's value to update `created` field. If that's so, then you need to create your own serializer field and override `field_from_native` (it doesn't return anything by default, that's why it doesn't have any effect in your case):

```
class EpochSerializerField(SerializerMethodField):
    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
        starttime = data['starttime']
        # generate `created` value using `starttime`

        into['created'] = created
        super(EpochSerializerField, self).field_from_native(data, files, field_name, into)
```

so the idea is simple, just reverse the calculation to generate `created` value and use your new serializer field. You can also move the content from the epoch method into `field_to_native` method of the new serializer field.

Comment: sorry could you clarify?  I could not get this example to work.  Do I change in #views.py the serializer I am using to EpochSerializerField?

Comment: Please see Kevin Stone's answer, which is much better and more clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code it will help you to solve your problem.

```
class UnixEpochDateField(serializers.DateField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))
```